# Extracting points from the MeshFunctions of Plot3D

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, mesh

I am trying to extract the points from the mesh lines of a 3D plot. (Not my actual function.)

```
   p = Plot3D[Sin[x]^2*Cos[y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},  MeshFunctions -> {#1^2+#2^2 &}]
```

[image: my plot]

I found a similar question [here](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/452424). So I used the code suggested:

```
p2 = p // Cases[#, GraphicsComplex[Line_, ___] :> Line] &;  
p3 = Flatten[p2, 1];  
ListPlot[p3[[All, 1 ;; 2]]]
```

[image: my attempt at extracting mesh lines]

As you can see, I am getting a bunch of points that are not on the mesh lines. When I increase the `PlotPoints`, it gets even worse.

How can I extract only the points on the mesh lines?

Comment: You will need to use `Normal[]` somewhere there…

Comment: Can you explain in more detail?

Comment: … I was trying to have you look at the docs for `Normal[]` and `GraphicsComplex[]`. In any event: use `Normal[p]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding @Guess comment:

```
p1 = Join @@ Cases[Normal@p, Line[x1__] :> x1, Infinity];
ListPlot[Most /@ p1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

```
p1 = Join @@ Cases[Normal@p, Line[x1__] :> 
                  {RGBColor @@ RandomReal[{0, 1}, 3], Line[Most /@ x1]}, Infinity];
Graphics[p1, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: The OP may want to set `BoundaryStyle -> None` if the boundary surrounding the contours is unwanted. If the surface is also not wanted and only the contours are desired, `PlotStyle -> None` can be added.

Answer (score 3):

Working with `GraphicsComplex` retains a degree of flexibility.  For instance,

```
Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[p[[1, 1]], Line[Rest@Cases[p, Line[z__] :> z, Infinity]]]]
```

[image]

gives the Mesh in 3D.  (`Rest@` deletes the perimeter of the surface.)  If, instead, a plot of the points in 3D is desired, use

```
Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[p[[1, 1]], 
  Point[Flatten[Rest@Cases[p, Line[z__] :> z, Infinity]]]]]
```

[image]

The same plot in 2D is obtained by dropping the last coordinate of each point.

```
p1 = Graphics[GraphicsComplex[Most /@ p[[1, 1]], 
   Point[Flatten[Rest@Cases[p, Line[z__] :> z, Infinity]]]]]
```

[image]

**Addendum**

A `List` of the points themselves can be obtained directly from `p`.

```
Most /@ (p[[1, 1, #]] & /@ Flatten[Rest@Cases[p, Line[z__] :> z, Infinity]])
```

or from p1, the 2D plot,

```
p1[[1, 1, #]] & /@ Flatten[Cases[p1, Point[z__] :> z, Infinity]]
```

which is equivalent to

```
Cases[Normal[p1], Point[z__] :> z, Infinity]
```

suggested by Guesswhoitis and belisarius.

Note: It might be tempting to try simply, `Most /@ (p[[1, 1, #]]`, but doing so also recovers hundreds of additional points used to construct the 3D surface.

**Explanation**

In response to a comment below, this is how (more or less) I obtained the results above.  To begin with, run

```
p//InputForm
```

to see what is inside, but be prepared for a lot of data. Basically, you will see the function `GraphicsComplex`, followed by several options at the very end. So, for instance,

```
Graphics3D[p[[1]]]
```

plots only the contents of the `GraphicsComplex`, which in this case is just the surface and the mesh lines.

The first argument of `GraphicsComplex` (see [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphicsComplex.html)) is a large array of 3D point locations, from which almost everything in the plot is constructed. The next argument consists of several other functions. What we care about here are `Line` functions, one for the boundary of the surface and one for each line in the mesh. The argument of Line is a list of indices, referring to the 3D points; i.e., `Line[{3 ,127, 52}]` draws a smooth curve from point `3` to point `127` to point `52`.

The command

`Line[Rest@Cases[p, Line[z__] :> z, Infinity]]`

extracts a list of the lists of indices, throws away the first list (which is the outline of the surface), and puts them inside another `Line` function.  Additionally `p[[1, 1]]` obtains the list of `3D points`  Finally, both of these items are repackaged in ``GraphicsComplex` and plotted.

```
Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[p[[1, 1]], Line[Rest@Cases[p, Line[z__] :> z, Infinity]]]]
```

giving the mesh lines in 3D shown in the first plot above.

If, instead, the Line indices are repackaged inside `Point`,

```
Point[Flatten[Rest@Cases[p, Line[z__] :> z, Infinity]]]
```

and combined with `p[[1, 1]]` inside `GraphicsComplex`, then

```
Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[p[[1, 1]], 
  Point[Flatten[Rest@Cases[p, Line[z__] :> z, Infinity]]]]]
```

gives a 3D plot of mesh points instead, as in the second plot above.

To obtain a 2D plot instead, use `Most` to discard the third dimension.

```
Graphics[GraphicsComplex[Most /@ p[[1, 1]], 
   Point[Flatten[Rest@Cases[p, Line[z__] :> z, Infinity]]]]]
```

which gives the third plot above.  I hope that this brief explanation is helpful.

Comment: As I noted in bel's answer, `BoundaryStyle -> None` will get rid of the lines enclosing the contours.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. Interestingly, `BoundaryStyle -> None` yields `806` points in my last plot, whereas `Rest@` leads to `801`.  Who knows?  Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Where indeed did those 5 points come from… :o

Comment: @bbgodfrey Those are beautiful. Thank you so much for taking the time to help. Even though this is all I really needed, I'm also curious how this works. How does Mathematica store the information of the 3D plot? It looks like p is stored as a list with the point stored in the first 2 levels somewhere. Then Cases[p, Line[z___], Infinity] picks out the mesh points. Is that right? What is the purpose of the :> z at the end?

Comment: @puppypalace  My response grew to be so long that I added it to the end of my Answer.  Best wishes.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Wow, InputForm looks incredibly useful. One thing I noticed when looking at the mesh lines individually is that sometimes Mathematica splits one mesh line into 4 pieces, one per Quadrant. For instance, I use pp = p[[1, 1, #]] & /@ Rest@Cases[p, Line[z__] :> z, Infinity] and grab pp[[24]]. Then I plot this set of points hoping to see the 24th mesh line. Instead, I only get one piece of the contour. pp[[25]] doesn't give me the next piece either. Do you know how to group the points by mesh lines so that pp[[1]] is one mesh line, pp[[2]] is another, etc...?

Comment: @puppypalace  Are your sure that you have not picked one of the lines near a corner, which naturally are broken into four quadrants?  In any case, the answer to your question is, "No".  I do not know the ordering of `Lines` in `p`, although you could try plotting some to see what you get.  Note that 28 lines are in one quadrant only, and just `8` are continuous loops.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Yes, you are right. When I did ListPlot[pp[[All, All, 1 ;; 2]]], Mathematica did not color the outer curves correctly, so it must not know they are in the same group. I also tried Table[ListPlot[pp[[i, All, 1 ;; 2]], AspectRatio -> 1], {i, Length[pp]}] and it doesn't look like the groups of points are in any sequential order. Any ways, thanks again for your info and explanations above. You've been a huge help.